# Postgresql - avoid database shutdown + vacuum error

Tags: postgresql, file, shutdown, vacuum

I have been receiving warning messages recently:

> WARNING:  database "mydb" must be vacuumed within xxxx transactions
>   HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a full-database VACUUM in
>   "mydb".

So I have tryed VACUUM, VACUUM FULL and VACUUM FULL FREEZE but all of the options end up with the same error:

> ERROR:  could not open file "base/19069/26252": No such file or directory

So... what can I do? I am desperate right now, I don't want the db to shutdown!

Comment: Do you have any disk errors? Check `dmesg` or check for SMART messages about drive failure. It sounds to me like things are getting confused.

Comment: I did it the hard way... I ran VACUUM several times and every time it stopped I deleted the table which was giving the error.

which would have been a better way?

Comment: When you say "deleted" you mean `DROP TABLE` right? Errors like that should not happen and suggest that your file system contents do not match the database's metadata about what tables exist. This is at least minor database corruption. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Yes I droped the tables. Looks like my filesystem is getting corrupted. thanks for the info.